# Compile error for method reference in multiple exception handling

Tags: java, compiler-errors, method-reference, catch-block

There is an interesting situation I have encountered. I have 2 exception classes `MyException1` and `MyException2`. During multiple catch(`MyException1 | MyException2 ex`) SonarLint suggests using method reference `(ex::getExitCode)` instead  of the lambda expression (`()=>ex.getExitCode()`). But if I follow the suggestion this time the compiler complains saying "Cannot resolve method 'getExitCode'". If I remove one of the exceptions compilation succeeds. So the code compiles only with one exception catch or I have to cast the class to the ancestor of the two. And if I cast it, SonarLint this time warns me about the unnecessary cast. Can someone explain what is going on here?

**MyException1**

```java
public class MyException1 extends RuntimeException implements ExitCodeGenerator {
    public MyException1 (String message, Throwable throwable) {
        super(message, throwable);
    }

    @Override
    public int getExitCode() {
        return -2;
    }
}
```

**MyException2**

```java
public class MyException2 extends RuntimeException implements ExitCodeGenerator {
    public MyException2 (String message, Throwable throwable) {
        super(message, throwable);
    }

    @Override
    public int getExitCode() {
        return -2;
    }
}
```

**Compile error**

```java
...
} catch (MyException1 | MyException2 ex) {
    System.exit(SpringApplication.exit(event.getApplicationContext(), ex::getExitCode);
} 
...
```

**Compiled**

```java
...
} catch (MyException1 | MyException2 ex) {
    System.exit(SpringApplication.exit(event.getApplicationContext(), ((ExitCodeGenerator)ex)::getExitCode);
} 
...
```

OR

**Compiled**

```java
...
} catch (MyException1 ex) {
    System.exit(SpringApplication.exit(event.getApplicationContext(), ex::getExitCode);
} 
...
```

Comment: What version of Java and Spring are you using?

Comment: I don't reproduce your issue btw.

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem, neither with Eclipse nor with javac. But what’s the purpose of writing `ex::getExitCode` or `() -> ex.getExitCode()` instead of just `ex`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of the multicatch is the type of ex.

It will be `Exception` and not `ExitCodeGenerator` that's why you have to cast the exception.

Comment: No, that’s not the problem. All compilers I tested, compiled the OP’s code without problems.